# explicit solution for transcendental equation

Tags: roots, transcendental-equations

Does anyone knows whether there is an explicit, analytical solution for transcendental equations of the form $A x + B \tanh(C x) + \coth(x) = 0$, where $A, B$, and $C$ are positive real constants?

Comment: Maple finds no analytical solution for $x+\coth(x)=0$.

Comment: What is the scope of this equation?

Comment: This equation appears in the solution of a heat transfer problem, in which a composite cylinder (two cylindrical slabs, with a non-zero thermal contact resistance) are subjected to a constant temperature at the bottom and zero heat flux at the top. More specifically, this equation gives the poles of a function for which I am looking for the inverse Laplace Transform.

Answer (score 2):

The Burniston-Siewert approach for anaytical solution of similar transcendental equation is by integral representations.

In :

http://www4.ncsu.edu/~ces/publist.html

You can find a lot of transcendental equations solved by such integrals, therefore you could adapt this method to your custom problem.

**?? HINT ??**

For a suitable complex path $\gamma$, x(A,B,C) can be written as:
$$x(A,b,C)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\gamma z\frac{A+\frac{BC}{\cosh(Cz)^2}-\frac{1}{\sinh(z)^2}}{Az+B\tanh(Cz)+\coth(z)}dz$$

**Historical Note**
In :
"The $W_t$ Transcendental Function and Quantum Mechanical Applications", V. E. Markushin, R. Rosenfelder, A. W. Schreiber, http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0104019v2

the equation $$x \tan(x) =y$$ has been investigated and the Lambert-like function $W_t(x)$ has been proposed. Such function is linked to the so called Lambert r-$W$ (i.e.  extension of Lambert series based on Laguerre polynomials).

Comment: Thank you very much! I will post the solution in case I find it!

Comment: If/when you find a solution, you should write a paper on that!

Comment: In  C. E. Siewert and C. J. Essig, "An Exact Solution of a Molecular Field Equation in the Theory of Ferromagnetism," Zeitschrift für Angewandte Mathematik und Physik, 24 (1973) 281-286

http://www4.ncsu.edu/~ces/pdfversions/56.pdf

solution  for $\zeta=\tanh\left(\frac{iz\zeta+h}{2}\right)$ has been found.

Comment: @TymaGaidash

I did not understand the question...

Comment: @giorgiomugnaini Okay, here is a concise question. How does the author go from equation $(2.13)$ to equation $(2.15)$ in this [paper](https://ces.math.ncsu.edu/pdfversions/52.pdf)?

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment on GEdgar's ($C=0$) version and the equation

$$
Ax+\coth(x)=0,
$$

(i.e. Find the points of intersection of the curve $y=\coth(x)$
and straight lines through the origin. 
Existence of real solutions requires $A$ to be of an appropriate sign.)

This can be solved using the functions in

I. Mező and A. Baricz,
On the generalization of the Lambert $W$ function with applications in theoretical physics.
arXiv:1408.3999v1.pdf (18 Aug 2014).

The starting point to using their functions is to rewrite the equation as

$$
\exp(2x)= \frac{x-1/A}{x+1/A}
$$

and then with $X=2x$ define

$$
f(X)= \frac{X+2/A}{X-2/A}\exp(X).
$$

The inverse function for f is defined in the arXiv paper (and earlier papers referenced there), and hence  the solution(s) for $f(X)=1$.

Remark. The inverse Langevin function can also be written in terms of the functions in their arXiv paper.

Comment: Hi Grant, welcome to the site!  I've edited your equations to make them render properly and added some formatting.  You may wish to take a look at the [MathJax tutorial and quick reference guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/5531).

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment
in response to giorgiomugnaini's
comment about an exact solution.
I an making it an answer
since entering the MathJax is much easier.

The "solution" 
to the equation
$ 0 = a + bx-x \tanh^{-1}(\frac1{x})$
is given, 
in equation (16),
when $a < 0$, by
$\frac1{x}
=2+\frac{1-a}{b}-\frac1{\pi}
\int_{-1}^1 \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{\pi t}{2(a+bt-t\tanh^{-1}(t))}\right) dt
$.

In view of the
*very* non-elementary nature
of that integral,
this does not seem to me
to be much of a help.

Comment: I have upvoted, because you have reported the Burniston-Siewert integral solution. I do not think this integral can be taken in a more "closed-form", but it can be numerically evaluated and it could be employed to identify links with other functions as Lambert W or  generalizations as r-Lambert W , possibly through some series expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [Lagrange Reversion](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjO2fKRpoj8AhWShHIEHX0gAD8QFnoECBEQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLagrange_reversion_theorem&usg=AOvVaw0Ywh3pLNY60VuwcRMItE3g) solution for the larger root of a more general equation:

$$x-(a \tanh( b y)+c \coth(y))=y\implies y=x+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{d^{n-1}(a\tanh(b x)+c\coth(x))^n}{dx^{n-1}}\mathop=^{r=\frac ac} x+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-c)^n}{n!}\frac{d^{n-1}(r\tanh(b x)+\coth(x))^n}{dx^{n-1}} $$

Compare results [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim+d-%3E-1.5+%28-1.5%2Bsum%5B%28-1%29%5En%2Fn%21+D%5B%28-0.4+tanh%280.3+d%29%2B0.2+coth%28d%29%29%5En%2C%7Bd%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C15%7D%5D%29) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-1.5++-%28+0.2+coth%28x%29+-0.4+tanh%280.3+x%29%29%3Dx). Now to use the binomial theorem:

$$\frac{d^{n-1}(r\tanh(b x)+\coth(x))^n}{dx^{n-1}} =\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk r^k\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\coth^{n-k}(x)\tanh^k(b x)$$

and somehow take the $n$th derivative of the hyperbolic functions using the [single exponential definiton](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1+-+2%2F%281+%2B+e%5E%282+x%29%29%3Dtanh%28x%29). More will be added

Comment: A [Fourier series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28coth%28x-3+pi%29%2Btanh%28x-3+pi%29%29%5E3%2C1%2F%282+pi%29sum%5Be%5E%28i+n+x%29+Nintegrate%5B%28coth%28x-3+pi%29%2Btanh%28x-3+pi%29%29%5E3+e%5E%28-i+n+x%29%2C%7Bx%2C-pi%2Cpi%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C-5%2C5%7D%5D) may work, but the coefficients are a little hard to find

Comment: Nice solution, thank you so much!

Comment: Note to self: $\frac {d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\left(\tanh^k(bx)\tanh^{k-n}(x)\right)$